# GsonBuilder registerTypeAdapter deserialization

Tags: java, android, gson, resttemplate, spring-android

I am having the following rest template (used for json requests to a server):

```
public RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Image.class, new ImageDeserializer());
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(MetaData.class, new MetaDataDeserializer());
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Vector.class, new VectorsDeserializer());

    GsonHttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
    jsonConverter.setGson(builder.create());

    FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> listHttpMessageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();


    listHttpMessageConverters.add(jsonConverter);
    listHttpMessageConverters.add(formHttpMessageConverter);
    listHttpMessageConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(listHttpMessageConverters);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

For some reason the third registerTypeAdapter call to the deserializer `VectorsDeserializer` does nothing. I am probably missing something here, any ideas/clarifications are very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `java.util.Vector`.

I so, I guess, it's because of using plain `Vector.class` instead of

```
new TypeToken<Vector<Whatever>>() {}.getType()
```

in the registration.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this line does? E.g. why is the `{}` necessary?

Comment: @MatthijsWessels By creating an anonymous class, the type information gets "reified", see https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained

Comment: Awesome thanks. So because `Vector` is itself a generic type, you can't use the `TypeVector::get`